# Is it possible to put SQLite file in Google Drive and use Google Drive API to update its data?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to use Google Drive as a SQL server. Can Google Drive API update data in SQLite files without having to downloading and uploading them?
What about XML files? Can Google Drive API update data in XML files without having to downloading and uploading them?

Comment: Where will be the process executed?

Comment: On application.

Comment: Why would you rule out SQL Server Express which is free of charge, or some other DBaaS solution?

Comment: I searched but I didn't find any free solution (without time limitation).

Comment: I store text, so I need less than 50MB storage.

Comment: take from here https://www.sqlite.org/howitworks.html
SQLite is a serverless software library, whereas the other systems are client-server based. SQLite runs in the same address space as the application, using the same program counter and heap storage. SQLite does no interprocess communication (IPC). When an application sends an SQL statement into SQLite (by invoking a the appropriate SQLite library subroutine), SQLite interprets the SQL in the same thread as the caller.

Comment: I don't believe that your plan will ever be able to work out.

Comment: Is there any free cloud database that has limited storage but unlimited service time?

Comment: You could try https://supabase.io/pricing
Although it's Pausing after 1 week inactivity, in which case you will have to login and reactivate

Comment: supabase says that its free services have up to a 2GB transfer limit. What does it mean? Will I have only 2GB traffic and after passing this amount, my service would be shut down forever?

Comment: Only Download Operations are counted towards the limit

Comment: SQL Server Express is free, as is PostgreSQL, MariaDB and MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google drive is a file storage system.   You can upload, download, list and update the meta data of files.  It does not have any access to edit the contents files themselves.  So you would need to upload and download the file.

The Google Docs api has the ability to edit google doc files but I would question what would happen to the formatting of the xml in a google doc file.

The google sheets api lets you edit google sheets documents I have seen people use that as a csv file to store data.

TBH you are using the wrong tool for the job.  There are a number of cloud based database solutions.  If you want to stick with google tech check out firebase.  MySql is also free as well as postgresql I have used both with C#